# Calculating the proportional weighted value in a specific segment: Make it more Pythonic

Tags: python, pandas

I have to make the following calculation (or similar) many times in my code and it takes a long time to run. I was wondering if it was possible to make the code more pythonic (reduce the time to run).

I am calculating the weighting of the "loan_size" proportional to all other loans that are have the same origination month

```
loan_plans['weighting'] = loan_plans.loan_size / loan_plans.apply(lambda S: loan_plans.loc[(loan_plans.origination_month == S.origination_month) 'loan_size'].sum(), axis=1)
```

The following is a set of example data with the desired result:

```
loan_size   origination_month   weighting
1000        01-2018             0.25
2000        02-2018             0.2
3000        01-2018             0.75
8000        02-2018             0.8
```

Comment: Please provide some example data and expected output.  Also: You don't use `S` in your lambda function.  Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish there?

Comment: @andrew_reece I have added the example data and expected output. I also updated the lambda function to include the S.

Comment: Thanks Brian.  What happened to `loan_number`?

Comment: @andrew_reece I changed it to origination month. The idea is that the function rolls through each entry and calculates the weighting based on what the current entry's origination_month is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** (per OP update):
There's nothing wrong with your approach; you might use `groupby` instead to get `origination_month` sums, and then do the weighting:

```
loan_plans = loan_plans.reset_index().merge(
    loan_plans.groupby("origination_month").loan_size.sum().reset_index(), on="origination_month"
)
loan_plans["weighting"] = loan_plans.loan_size_x / loan_plans.loan_size_y
loan_plans.sort_values("index").set_index("index")

       loan_size_x origination_month  loan_size_y  weighting
index                                                       
0             1000           01-2018         4000       0.25
1             2000           02-2018        10000       0.20
2             3000           01-2018         4000       0.75
3             8000           02-2018        10000       0.80
```

Cosmetics:

```
(loan_plans
    .sort_values("index")
    .set_index("index")
    .rename(columns={"loan_size_x": "loan_size"})
    .drop("loan_size_y", 1))

       loan_size origination_month  weighting
index                                        
0           1000           01-2018       0.25
1           2000           02-2018       0.20
2           3000           01-2018       0.75
3           8000           02-2018       0.80
```

**Earlier answer**
You can use `div` and `sum`, no need for `apply`:

```
loan_plans.loan_size.div(
    loan_plans.loc[loan_plans.loan_number.eq(1), "loan_size"].sum()
)
```

Output:

```
0     0.024714
1     0.053143
2     0.012143
3     0.010929
4     0.039643
           ...
```

Data:

```
N = 100
data = {"loan_size": np.random.randint(100, 1000, size=N), 
        "loan_number": np.random.binomial(n=1, p=.3, size=N)}
loan_plans = pd.DataFrame(data)
```